# Android - Intent.setType() arguments

Tags: android, file, android-intent, sms

Does anyone know all available arguments for this method? Like "image/..." or "file/..."? I didn't found a clue for that list in official documentation.

Speccially, I need an intent to send contact (.vcf) file. But type "file/vcf" doesn't show me send via sms option.

```
sendIntent.setData(Uri.parse("sms:"))
```

Also didn't help

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Intent.setType() [takes the MIME type as an argument](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#setType%28java.lang.String%29).

The MIME type is [text/vcard](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6350#section-3)

Comment: It's very close, but I have nullpointerexception when I'm trying to send MMS with vCard

Here is the code: 
Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE);
sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(outputFile));
sendIntent.setType("text/vcard");

Answer (score 0):

How about `Intent.setAction`? For example to send sms:

```
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setData(Uri.parse("sms:" + phonenumberhere));
```

`Action View` is kind of a generic handler in this case, but when combined with phonenumber and sms it will send text.