# Mail attachment does not have correct Content-Type

Tags: android, android-intent, email-attachments

I want to enable my Android app to send a file from one device to another device in various ways (mail, bluetooth, whatever).

My first use case is email. This is the code I'm using to generate my SEND intent.

```java
            Intent shareIntent = new Intent();
            shareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            shareIntent.setType("text/xml");
            shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, getResources().getText(R.string.share_list)));
```

When I run this on the simulator (Android 2.1), the attachment section of the resulting mail reads:

```
Content-Type: ;
```

However, when I run this on my Galaxy Nexus (Android 4.2.2), the attachment section reads:

```
Content-Type: application/tpl;
```

This might be because the passed URI ends in `.tpl`.

This is what I would have expected:

```
Content-Type: text/xml;
```

Am I missing something here? It is important that the mail attachment has the correct MIME type so I can use intent filters for the receiving side of the application.

Comment: Did you try to attach one of those files using the e-mail app and see what the attachment section reads? I think you'll get the same.

Comment: This depends on the e-mail client also. As mentioned by @Marina.Eariel, try attaching files directly from various e-mail clients and you might be surprised by the results. A way to handle this is to have a custom file extension for your application and make your intent filter use that for discerning what files should it handle.

Comment: this attachment work in device not emulator because in emulator not have email app.try this in device.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are referring the Web content types,

You should have this type in your case (email/message) `i.setType("message/rfc822");`

see this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13065838/what-are-the-possible-intent-types-for-intent-settypetype)

I hope this will do..

Answer (score 0):

**for whats app this code works...as whats app needs few more details than the data..so heres the deal**

```
                               Intent waIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);

                               waIntent.setType("text/plain");
                               waIntent.setPackage("com.whatsapp");
                               waIntent.setType("image/*");
                               waIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, INFO);
                               waIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(new File(file_PATH)));


                               startActivity(Intent.createChooser(waIntent, "Share with Whatsapp"));

                 for other such as gmail or any mail - just remove the package and set type whatever you like an iamge or file or anything that it supports,for bluetooth it works too...and for whats app i shared the code with you.
```

hope it all helps you

Answer (score 0):

I have a few suggestions.

1. use setData instead of putExtra. Or are you already using setData for something else? In any case, set the mime type AFTER you've set the data. from the docs of setdata: "Set the data this intent is operating on. This method automatically clears any type that was previously set by setType(String) or setTypeAndNormalize(String)." http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#setData(android.net.Uri)
2. use setType *after* you use putExtra. It might be that when you use putExtra, the mime type is (erroneously) inferred from the data, overwriting the mime type you've just set.
3. use setDataAndType(Uri data, String type). The docs say you should rarely use it, because the mime type should be inferred from the data, but if that doesn't work for you, you could still try this. from the docs: "This method should very rarely be used -- it allows you to override the MIME type that would ordinarily be inferred from the data with your own type given here." http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#setDataAndType(android.net.Uri,%20java.lang.String)

EDIT:
The suggestions above are for setting the right content type, not for getting only email apps to show up in the app chooser dialog. There's no right way in Android to get only email apps in the app chooser dialog. Your app can and should only specify the type of content you want to send, other apps can specify whether they can send your type of content. That could be an email app, but also "what's app" for example. Why would you want to limit the user's ability to send the file to email apps only anyway? 
If you want the file to be sent to a specific email address, that's different, then you should set the email address of the recipient on the Intent; then only email apps will show up in the app chooser dialog.