# Intent chose file - How to set type as a .keystore?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-afilechooser

I'm trying to select a file using the Intent `.ACTION_GET_CONTENT`

```
Intent chooseFile = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
chooseFile.setType("*/*");
chooseFile = Intent.createChooser(chooseFile, "Select keystore");
startActivityForResult(chooseFile, 1001);
```

This displays all files to select from.

With this SO answer:

[What are the possible intent types for intent.setType(type)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13065838/what-are-the-possible-intent-types-for-intent-settypetype)

It displays a list of file types that I can set for the Intent, however I can't find an option for selecting only a `.keystore` file (for a crypto wallet).

How would I add that type as the intent?

Comment: I do not see signs of there being a MIME type for that. And, even if there were one, I expect that few Android devices would be set up to recognize that MIME type. Most likely `*/*` is as good as you are going to get.

Comment: I found this list of media types ```https://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/media-types.xhtml```. Does this mean all these MIME types are supported by Android that I can set the Type as? I'm not sure

Comment: "Does this mean all these MIME types are supported by Android that I can set the Type as?" -- not necessarily. First, the list that you cited is updated from time to time, but Android devices rarely get OS updates. Second, I don't know that Google commits to supporting all those MIME types even on newer versions of Android.

Comment: Ah okay, thanks!